# Pass the values to rest api from magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.2, rest-api

Get the values from magento2 checkout page but I need to pass into the rest api. How to pass the values.

```
*$params =   array( 'OrderLineId'=>$orderLineId,
                        'MaterialNo'=>$materialNo,
                        'PlanType'=>$planType,
                        'Qty'=>$qty,
                        'UnitPrice'=>$unitPrice,
                        'UnitTax'=>$UnitTax,
                        'DiscountRate'=>$DiscountRate,
                        'Discount'=>$Discount,
                        'OrderId'=>$orderId,
                        'StoreId'=>$storeId,
                        'PartnerId'=>  $partnerId,
                        'CustomerId'=> $customerId,
                        'OrderType'=> $orderType,
                        'OrderSource'=>  $orderSource,
                        'CurrId'=> $currId,
                        'UserName'=> $userName);
                        $data = json_encode($params);
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

         } catch (Exception $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage(); exit;
              }
```

Can you anyone please help me.

Comment: When you need to send the data? Before the order is finished, when the checkout page is loaded? Depending on your answer, the best approach would be creating a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). There you could put your business logic.

Comment: Before place an order I fetch the data through the observer. But I ran this page not posting to API.

Comment: then you can listen to the event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` it dispaches `['order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote()]` At your observer you could use

`$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()`

in order to get the order.

Comment: values are not passing to rest API from this data

Comment: You may be doing something wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a observer, you could listen to event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`

Take a look into `vendor/magento/module-downloadable/etc/events.xml`

You will see:

```
 <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
    <observer name="checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after" instance="Magento\Downloadable\Observer\SetHasDownloadableProductsObserver" />
</event>
```

You can implement you logic the same way that `Magento\Downloadable\Observer\SetHasDownloadableProductsObserver` class does. Check the method `execute`

```
/**
 * Set checkout session flag if order has downloadable product(s)
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getHasDownloadableProducts()) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /* @var $item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
            if ($item->getProductType() == \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE
                || $item->getRealProductType() == \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE
                || $item->getProductOptionByCode(
                    'is_downloadable'
                )
            ) {
                $this->_checkoutSession->setHasDownloadableProducts(true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You just need to adapt the code to your needs. Most of your work is copy and paste.

:)